# Printing API response to column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a function that will make an API call then print the response to the next column in the row for each row in the sheet. For example, I have the two variables in columns A and B, the call is made using those variables, and I want the response to that call in column C until no more rows are left.

I am having problems with printing that response to each column for each row. Right now I have it printing the newest response in C2. I need those responses to be in their correct row. Below is the function I have written.

```
function trust() {
    var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    rows.forEach(function(rows, index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            var link = rows[0];
            console.log(link);
            var shard = rows[1];
      //var error = rows[2]
            console.log(shard);
            //Building API Call
            var url = String(link).concat("/api/v1/accounts/self/trust_links")
            console.log(url)
            var data = {
                "trust_link[managing_account_id]":shard,
            };
      console.log(data)
            var options = {
                "method": "post",
        'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": ''
                },
                'payload': data,
            };
            console.log(options);
            //API Call
            var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
            Logger.log(response);
      //Print each API response to Column C
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2").setValue(response)
        }
    });
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm having trouble is not a question.  What is your question? Are you getting an error and if so what is the exact error and what line is causing it?

Comment: Can you provide us with any visuals (e.g a sample screenshot with your dummy data) just to see how the arrangement for the rows and column works. Else, you can consider Coopers answer if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(index + 1, 3).setValue(response)`

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the help!